# Google Maps Engine for ios?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-app-engine

I have some trouble.

Can i create custom layer in Google Maps Engine an show it in my app what use [google map SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Enterprise version of the Maps SDK for both IOS and Android now includes Maps Engine support. This is a paid for product. You should contact [Google Enterprise](http://www.google.com/enterprise/) sales for more information.